# What is the simplest way to change the login background in Fedora (17)?

Tags: fedora, login

I want to change the login screen of my Fedora 17 box. I found some instructions on the web saying a lot about manually editing *gconf* settings:

```
$ su -
$ su - gdm -s /bin/bash
$ `dbus-launch | sed "s/^/export /"`
$ GSETTINGS_BACKEND=dconf gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/<filename>"
```

Isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: See http://fabhax.com/technology/change-wallpapers-in-gnome-3.4/ for a step by step instruction on how to change each of the three wallpapers on GNOME 3. This article is written for Debian though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple way without installing additional packages:

```
$ su -
$ xhost +si:localuser:gdm
$ sudo -u gdm gnome-control-center
```

Comment: In my opinion this is even simpler than gdm3setup because it does not require installing an rpm beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

Chaange the image in the directory

```
/usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default/wide/beefy-miracle.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do all that work? why not just change: /usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default/wide/beefy-miracle.png to the image you want?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot. I was trying the method you listed yesterday, and after running this file, I got everything working! I don't know if I had to take some of the steps listed above, or if this thing will run right out of the package, but its worth a shot!

It's called gdm3setup, and if you click view raw on the website attached, it should download as an .rpm file and you should be able to install it with the [package](https://github.com/Nano77/various/blob/master/rpm/gdm3setup-20120510-1.noarch.rpm) installer. Way easier.

Also attached is a screenshot of the running program, there are some pretty cool  things to tweak in there!

Comment: screenshot's missing

Comment: Thanks for the rpm. Would be great to have a repo for it.