# How do I change the lockscreen background in Gnome 3 (Fedora 17)?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, lock-screen

While seeking a solution to my [login background question](https://superuser.com/questions/433975/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-change-the-login-background-in-fedora-17) I realized that the lockscreen has to be configured seperately. But how? On a quick google search I only found the suggestion to replace the images in the Adwaita theme. Is there a better way?

Comment: See http://fabhax.com/technology/change-wallpapers-in-gnome-3.4/ for a step by step instruction on how to change each of the three wallpapers on GNOME 3. This article is written for Debian though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

edit /usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default/beefy-miracle.xml,change the picture path which you set as below:

```
<!-- Wide 16:10 -->
<size width="1920" height="1200">/usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default/wide/SundownDunes.jpg</size>
<!-- Standard 4:3 -->
<size width="2048" height="1536">/usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default/standard/SundownDunes.jpg</size>
<!-- Normalish 5:4 -->
<size width="1280" height="1024">/usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default/normalish/SundownDunes.jpg</size>
```

Comment: It's not nearly as nice and simple as it should be. I would love to see a UI based tweak tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

I did a straight replacement of existing images. I have performed other hacks to change the logon wallpaper, but I am guessing that this will also address the logon wallpaper.

Fedora 17 path is: /usr/share/backgrounds/beefy-miracle/default
and from there you have /normalish; /standard; /wide
and within each is beefy-miracle.png

Comment: This method works, but keep in mind that it will likely create trouble when upgrading to a later release of fedora.

Answer (score 1):

i just found that in Fedora 20 (Gnome 3.10) they made a UI for changing the lockscreen background.

go to the settings, and open the background options, there are 2 choices one for the normal background and one for the lockscreen